i want deform this metal strip by using this bending machine
I want deform this metal strip by using this bending machine. Which physics should I use soft body ? rigid body ? and what is method to use related physics? I applied rigid body and soft body physics but its not working what I want.

I don't know if you can do it correctly with physics, maybe simply use an armature to bend your object?


yes i know physics rules you can just tell me.. how to do it using physics

By using armature object does not bend in uniform way. i mean i does not become proper " L " shape.

You can make it look sharper, you just need to have the proper topology
